# Download from S3 in Laravel works with PDF, not with JPG

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

Im using the following code:

```
$file = Storage::disk('s3')->getDriver()->readStream(attachmentPath().$attachment->filename);

return \Response::stream(function() use($file) {
    fpassthru($file);
    }, 200, [
        'Content-Type' => $attachment->mimetype,
        'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=' . $attachment->filename,
        'Content-Length' => $attachment->size
]);
```

The variables used respond to (with pdf or jpg as example):

- "mimetype" (application/pdf or image/jpeg)
- "filename" (ex: 240-ivlvei-pdf.pdf or 240-zi1gdv-ddvj63hxsaqn0az.jpg)
- "size" in bytes

---

With PDF's, it works perfectly.

**With images/gif it downloads damaged.**

But can't figure out why. I assume is something to do with headers or something like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work as an application/octet-stream?  (Can you open it after download)

Answer (score 0):

Try using getObject method and see if it works (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrieveObjSingleOpPHP.html)

```
                    $downloader = $s3->getObject(array(
                            'Bucket' => $bucket,
                            'Key'    => $object['Key'],
                            'SaveAs' => dirname(__FILE__)."/name_of_file.jpg"
                    ));
```